# how can i use button click event and onclientclick together

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a dynamic button when click a pop up appear and user key in then submit.

First of all I have dynamic button created depends on the table row

```
TableCell tc;
for (int i = 1; i < Approval_TBL.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    TableRow tr = Approval_TBL.Rows[i];
    tr.Cells.Add(tc = new TableCell());
    Button tb = new Button();
    tb.ID = Convert.ToString(i);
    tb.Text = "Reject";
    tb.CssClass = "btn btn-default";
    tb.OnClientClick = "javascript:$find('popup1').show();return false;__doPostBack('btnReject_click','')";
    tb.Click += new EventHandler(btnReject_click);

    tc.Controls.Add(tb);
}
```

then I have the popup created using ajax:

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="1"
    BehaviorID="popup1" 
    PopupControlID="Panel1"
    DropShadow="true"
    CancelControlID="Button3"
    OnOkScript="OkButtonClick"
    BackgroundCssClass="BackgroundStyle" />
```

then I have created click event

```
protected void btnReject_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code
}
```

Currently looks like it only run Onclientclick event where the popup appear but it wont go in to btnReject_click. but if i remove the onclientclick, it will be able to go in the btnReject_click.

My way of doing is weird because i dont know how to use asp.net and most of my code i put it in server side (c#).

Comment: Onclientclick you specified **return false** so no code will execute further..
**tb.OnClientClick = "javascript:$find('popup1').show();__doPostBack('btnReject_click','')";**

Comment: ok. for 1 days study finally understand!! onclientclick is on client side and click is on server side. so it will fire onclientclick first before it go to the server side click.

Answer (score 0):

if you using jQuery then

```
$("selector").on('click',function(){
 // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your `OnClientClick` you `return false;`. Anything after that is not executed so the postback never happens. Remove the return and the postback should fire.

```
tb.OnClientClick = $find('popup1').show();__doPostBack('btnReject_click','');";
```

Comment: it still wont fire the event for btnReject_click